# vue components doesn't return value

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I have created this component and use $emit to call getNames from other file:

```
<div class="mt-1 relative rounded-md shadow-md">
          <input
            v-model="ticker"
            @keydown.enter="addClick"
            @input="getNames"
            type="text"
            name="wallet"
            id="wallet"
            class="block w-full pr-10 border-gray-300 text-gray-900 focus:outline-none focus:ring-gray-500 focus:border-gray-500 sm:text-sm rounded-md"
            placeholder="DOGE"
          />
        </div>
        <div class="flex bg-white shadow-md p-1 rounded-md shadow-md flex-wrap">
          <span
            class="inline-flex items-center px-2 m-1 rounded-md text-xs font-medium bg-gray-300 text-gray-800 cursor-pointer"
            v-for="t of getNames()"
            :key="t.name"
            @click="pushName(t)"
          >
            {{ t }}
          </span>
        </div>
import addButton from "./addButton.vue";
export default {
  components: {
    addButton,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      ticker: "",
    };
  },
  methods: {
    addClick() {
      this.$emit("add-ticker", this.ticker);
      this.ticker = "";
    },
    getNames(){
      this.$emit("get-name", this.ticker);
    }
```

It's working but it doesn't return value to my component and I don't get list of names, it worked successful without component. In other file i have this code:

```
<add-ticker @get-name="getNames" @add-ticker='addClick'/>
    getNames(ticker) {
      let filtred = this.coinNames.filter((filtered) =>
        filtered.toUpperCase().startsWith(ticker.toUpperCase())
      );
      console.log(filtred.slice(0,4))

      return filtred.slice(0, 4);
```

Comment: `getNames()` (in the first code) is a method that is emitting `get-name` ... why do you think that function returns a value

Comment: @JaromandaX not sure what you mean. It's method in main vue file too(i know need to use computed, i guess in this case it doesn't matter)

Comment: `v-for="t of getNames()"` and `getNames` is `getNames(){ this.$emit("get-name", this.ticker); }` - no return statement ... am I missing something?

Comment: did you think that `v-for="t of getNames()"` would call a function in a different file because *it's what you want it to do*?

Comment: @JaromandaX but it should call getNames() from second code and it have to return value? If it's not right, how to return value from second code to my component? It's my first components and I think I don't know much about it

Comment: @JaromandaX I just thought it works like AddClick, but there is not return value.

Comment: `but it should call getNames() from second code` why? the code in the first block knows nothing about functions in `<add-ticker` ... `getNames` in the first block emits an event, which runs the code in `<add-ticker` ... but there's still no `return` in the function in the FIRST block so `v-for="t of getNames()"` is effectively `v-for="t of undefined"` - and you're `getNames` for `@input="getNames"` ... so it's like you expect that function to server two purposes

Comment: @JaromandaX Okay, I understand I need to get return value to my first getNames from second and then return it in component. I tried to do this with props, bind new value which I set in getNames() of main file, but it was bad. I don't know how to make props with function, or return needed value with emit.

Comment: Parent communicates to child using props. Child communicates to parent using emits. Or. Use global state like with pinia or vuex in vue2